# Having two views/panes in a view controller

Tags: ios, swift

[Here image from AliExpress iphone app.Kindly view this first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiPJ0.png)

I had to implement it. Now that i have implemented the custom segmented control programmatically(not the default segmented control interface builder component), i am unable to perform some action once it's clicked. The situation is:   As i posted below, i have that code in a class. and i have two container views linked to another class. What i want is that once i click these, the container views data gets changed. I have implementing it by creating instance of other class and accessing the methods but i am getting nil value errors and app is crashing. Can you please tell me how to do that? I can't directly link those as outlets to containers views classes as they are not interface components but programmatically implemented segmented controls.

Please help. thanks

Comment: Possibly some sort of custom segmented control...

Comment: Thanks Linus G, now i know what it's and i can now search about its implementation on google. I will write here if i come across any issues.

Comment: You should post your results as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that you are looking for a segmented control using containers.

Comment: Thanks DanyIS, now i know what it's and i can now search about its implementation on google. I will write here if i come across any issues.

Comment: So could you please upvote my question if you can and press 'validate' button ? :D